# Issue with back button Name in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

First View Controller to Second View Controller to Move.
First View Controller Name is Information.
and 
Issue is when I reach to the Second View Controller then I found back button Name as Back.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X1e2.png)
When I turn the simulator to landscape view then back button title is as "Information"
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gZAp.png)
What is the issue there? I could not understand.

Comment: Where do you set the name for the back button?

Comment: When you turn the simulator to landscape view then what it shows??

Comment: What is the name of your second view controller?
If the name is too large, you might find that iOS will change the back button name to Back so that everything can fit.

Comment: iOS shows "Back" when the actual title is too long to fit in the button. There is no issue. It's normal.

Comment: Just turn the simulator to landscape view, if back button title is as "Information"... then there is no issue... your title is too long thats why it show Back instead of information

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Your Title Name" 
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(OnClick_btnBack:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnBack;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the observed behavior (which is normal).

Answer (score 0):

Write below line of code in first view controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.style target:nil action:nil];
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the observed behavior (which is normal).

Comment: Thanks....my solved this error..